# A Circular linked list with no pointers

Tags: java, node.js, iterator

I am trying to complete a Circular doubly linked List programming project.  We are suppose to create the Link List class with `Node<E>` Head as the only instant variable. The only instant variable in the inner class is Node current. The Node class had three instant variables, `E data`, `Node<E> next`, and `Node<E> prev`.

In a test program that uses our `CDLL` call we are suppose to use the `next()` and `hasNext()` method of the iterator inner class to loop through the entire list once printing out each node.  The problem I am having is I can't figure out how the `hasNext()` method can know when one loop has been completed and every node has been printed.

In other words, how can I get `hasNext()` to return true when current==head on the first iteration of the loop and return false when `current==head` at the beginning of the second loop.

I greatly appreciate any insight that you may have.

Comment: Use a flag variable like a `boolean` to control if it's the second time you're checking for the head node.

Comment: I have never heard the term "instant variable" before.  Perhaps you should explain yourself using a code example: one example to say how it's supposed to look, and one example to demonstrate what you're not allowed to do.

Comment: I am sure he means "instance variable."

Comment: Show code.  Hard to really understand what you're actually trying to do, and what the limitations are here.

Answer (score 0):

With limitation of instance variables, it seems impossible.

But, if you do not link your tail node to head node, you can implement "hasNext".

Then it won't be circular anymore.

But you don't have to make the list actually circular.

if you found next node is null, get the head node instead.

Then it will be virtually circular.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

> In other words, how can I get hasNext() to return true when current==head on the first iteration of the loop and return false when current==head at the beginning of the second loop.

So your issue is that you thing current==head is what matters.  That's not what matters, what matters in the circular case is the nextNode() - that is, what will be coming up next?

So Assuming HEAD is a reference to the start of your list, and that the last nodes .next() points to the HEAD node.

```
// psudocode.
boolean hasNext() 
   if current.next() == head 
       return false
   else
      return true
```

EDIT:

Ok here's a very simple version of how to do this iteration

```
public void iterateAndPrint(Node head) :
   Node current = head;
   // check for null case
   if(current == null)
       return
   // case of list where ther eis only one node - HEAD...
   if(!current.hasNext())  
       print current.name
       return
   // ok so the nodes aren't empty, and there are more than just the head node.
   while(true): 
      // as long as has next returns true, print the name and then set current to next node
      if(current.hasNext())
          print current.name
          current = current.next()
      // has next returned false - we're on the last node.  Make sure it's not equal to Head (redundant at this point)
      else if (!current.hasNext() && current!=head) 
          print current.name
          break
      // i don't think this is strictly nescesary, but better safe than sorry.
      else:
          break      
public void hasNext(Node current, Node head):
      if(current.next() == head):
          return false
      else:
          return true
```

Comment: So I tried using current.next idea.  However, when I make current.next==false the program doesn't print out the last node.

Comment: So I tried using current.next idea.  However, when I make current.next==false the program doesn't print out the last node.  A while loop in the test program check hasNext() and if returns true it calls the next method.  Here is my next metho                 public E next()                                                     If(!hasNext())
throw new NoSuchElementException();
 E toReturn = current.data;
current = current.next;
 return toReturn;

Comment: Please post the entire block of code, including the print.  It's hard to read in comments.  I think it's probably a bug in your printing logic.  I also don't understand what you mean by "current.next == false"?  That doesn't make much sense here.

Comment: Is your print in the next method?  It shouldn't be.